# AJAXX AutoComplete joins and unions causing error

Tags: 7, database, ajax

I am a bit out of my depth here.

I have successfully implemented my own autocomplete field of an entityform, the following link was my roadmap [Textfield that uses AutoComplete.](https://www.drupal.org/node/854216)

But I am trying to do something much more fancier. I need to search for a users name, and autocomplete it for the user. The issue I am having is that I must check multiple tables for the user to select from, tables like: `field_data_field_first_name`, `field_data_field_othername`, `field_data_field_nickname`, `field_data_field_fullname`.

Because some people's names have changed, or have a nickname.

So I have begun checking multiple tables and think I got a good start, but I keep getting the following error: `"SQLSTATE[21000]: Cardinality violation: 1222 The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns"`

I want to be able to incorporate this:

```
 SELECT fn.*, ln.* FROM field_data_field_first_name as fn 
    left join field_data_field_last_name as ln ON fn.entity_id = ln.entity_id 
    WHERE fn.field_first_name_value LIKE '%bun%' 
UNION
SELECT fn.*, fo.* FROM field_data_field_first_name as fn
    left join field_data_field_other_name as fo ON fn.entity_id = fo.entity_id
    WHERE fn.field_first_name_value LIKE '%bun%'
UNION 
SELECT ni.*, ln.* FROM field_data_field_nickname as ni 
    left join field_data_field_last_name as ln on ni.entity_id = ln.entity_id 
    WHERE ni.field_nickname_value LIKE '%bun%' 
UNION
SELECT ni.*, fo.* FROM field_data_field_nickname as ni 
    LEFT JOIN field_data_field_other_name as fo ON ni.entity_id = fo.entity_id
    WHERE ni.field_nickname_value LIKE '%bun%'
```

into Drupal 7 `db_select`. I have some of this query in my Drupal query (not all of it, for the moment) but I am getting the column discrepency error (1222), my column counts aren't matching. Can't I just grab every field, like I do in my MySQL string and call it a day? I thought `fields('alias')` would of solved this, since that is grabbing every column, but it doesn't seem to be doing the trick!
This is what I got now:

```
$secondQuery = db_select('field_data_field_first_name', 'f') ->fields('f')
      // check the first_name_value, but we want to do a leftJoin to show the left_name_value as well! like Larry, Adams, not just Larry
      ->condition('field_first_name_value', '%'. db_like($string) .'%', 'LIKE');
    $secondQuery->leftJoin('field_data_field_last_name', 'l', 'f.entity_id = l.entity_id');
    $secondQuery->fields('l');

  // Make the query
  $result = db_select('field_data_field_user_name', 'u')
      ->fields('u')
      ->condition('field_user_name_value', '%' . db_like($string) . '%', 'LIKE')
      ->union($secondQuery)
      ->execute();
```

Comment: Why are you adding the same query object to the union? Is there a reason you're trying to do a union?

Comment: Well... Now you are forcing me to second guess myself. My sql isn't up to par, and maybe im going about it the wrong way. I want to check against like 5 tables for the users name. Which ever of the tables' columns is closer to what the user wants. So they start typing in lar, for larry, it checks 5 tables and compares '%lar%' with a unique column in each table. It seemed like a union would work. The join is so if i got a match in the first_name table i want the last_name table to display last name with the first name. I can send some ss tomorrow if what im saying makes no sense.

Comment: Sorry, I misread the code and  did not see the `$result =` statement for some reason, and thought secondQuery was running itself. :|

Comment: Ahh, yeah :-). Not a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I figured out how to convert MySQL to Drupal SQL, of a join and union sql transaction, I am not done - but this is the start and the rest is just copy / paste and massage.

```
$matches = array();
  $debug_stop = "";

  // Firstname and Lastname - Larry Adams
  $firstname_lastname_query = db_select('field_data_field_first_name', 'f') 
     ->fields('f')
    ->condition('field_first_name_value', '%'. db_like($string) .'%', 'LIKE');
  $firstname_lastname_query->leftJoin('field_data_field_last_name', 'l', 'f.entity_id = l.entity_id');
  $firstname_lastname_query->fields('l');

  // Username checks - lAdams
  $username_query = db_select('field_data_field_user_name', 'u')
      ->fields('u')
      ->condition('field_user_name_value', '%' . db_like($string) . '%', 'LIKE');
  $username_query->leftJoin('field_data_field_last_name', 'l', 'u.entity_id = l.entity_id');
  $username_query->fields('l');

  // Unionize the query to previous query
  $firstname_lastname_query->union($username_query);

  // Nickname checks - lar-bear Adams
  $nickname_lastname_query = db_select('field_data_field_nickname', 'ni')
      ->fields('ni')
      ->condition('field_nickname_value', '%' . db_like($string) . '%', 'LIKE');
  $nickname_lastname_query->leftJoin('field_data_field_last_name', 'l', 'ni.entity_id = l.entity_id');
  $nickname_lastname_query->fields('l');

  // Unionize the query to previous query
  $firstname_lastname_query->union($nickname_lastname_query);

  // Execute the query
  $result = $firstname_lastname_query->execute();


  $debug_stop = "";
  // save the query to matches
  foreach ($result as $row) {
    // If we returned back a user_name accessible field
    if (isset($row->field_user_name_value)) {
      $matches[$row->field_user_name_value] = check_plain($row->field_user_name_value);
    }
    // If we returned back a first_name_value accessible field
    if (isset($row->field_first_name_value)) {
      // with a last name
      if ($row->field_last_name_value) {
       $first_last_name = $row->field_first_name_value ." ". $row->field_last_name_value;
       $matches[$first_last_name] = check_plain($first_last_name);
      }
    }

  }  

  // Return the result to the form in json
  drupal_json_output($matches);
```